# Spring app in Docker-Tomcat container runs on one host, fails on another

Tags: java, spring, macos, docker, tomcat

We have a SpringBoot app which should run in a Tomcat instance in a Docker container, the problem is that the Spring app fails to startup on my MacOS host but successfully starts up on a Ubuntu host.

EDIT: The same war is running on a tomcat server (on my mac - no docker) fine, but in the docker container it is not working!

Log for Spring Application start:

```
2018-06-20 13:28:12.123  INFO 7 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1073 ms
2018-06-20 13:28:12.176  WARN 7 --- [ost-startStop-1] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletRegistrationBean' defined in class path resource [frontend/spring/report/BirtEngineServletConfiguration.class]: 
  Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean]: Factory method 'servletRegistrationBean' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Basically this type of error is happening everytime, even if I remove the whole Birt Stack of our application, then the faulty classes will be just some others.

This led me to the suspicion that my environment could cause the error, because the difference between my log to the log of my colleagues is that the following only appears on my host but not on the other hosts:

```
13:28:10.333 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding PropertySource 'servletConfigInitParams' with lowest search precedence
13:28:10.336 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding PropertySource 'servletContextInitParams' with lowest search precedence
13:28:10.341 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding PropertySource 'jndiProperties' with lowest search precedence
13:28:10.342 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding PropertySource 'systemProperties' with lowest search precedence
13:28:10.342 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding PropertySource 'systemEnvironment' with lowest search precedence
13:28:10.342 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [StubPropertySource@354020215 {name='servletConfigInitParams', properties=java.lang.Object@5420df83}, StubPropertySource@825691136 {name='servletContextInitParams', properties=java.lang.Object@51372fd5}, JndiPropertySource@196027607 {name='jndiProperties', properties=org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate@59a13ee6}, MapPropertySource@1350532830 {name='systemProperties', properties={java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, java.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources, sun.boot.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/jre8/lib/amd64, java.vm.version=25.161-b12, shared.loader=, java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation, java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/, path.separator=:, tomcat.util.buf.StringCache.byte.enabled=true, java.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties, java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, file.encoding.pkg=sun.io, user.country=US, sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD, sun.os.patch.level=unknown, tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToScan=log4j-web*.jar,log4j-taglib*.jar,log4javascript*.jar,slf4j-taglib*.jar, java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification, user.dir=/opt/tomcat, java.runtime.version=1.8.0_161-b12, java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment, java.endorsed.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/jre8/lib/endorsed, os.arch=amd64, java.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp, line.separator=
, java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.apache.naming, java.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager, os.name=Linux, ignore.endorsed.dirs=, sun.jnu.encoding=ANSI_X3.4-1968, java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib, java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification, java.class.version=52.0, sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers, os.version=4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs, java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.threadFactory=org.apache.catalina.startup.SafeForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory, user.home=/root, catalina.useNaming=true, user.timezone=Etc/UTC, java.awt.printerjob=sun.print.PSPrinterJob, file.encoding=ANSI_X3.4-1968, java.specification.version=1.8, tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip=bootstrap.jar,commons-daemon.jar,tomcat-juli.jar,annotations-api.jar,el-api.jar,jsp-api.jar,servlet-api.jar,websocket-api.jar,jaspic-api.jar,catalina.jar,catalina-ant.jar,catalina-ha.jar,catalina-storeconfig.jar,catalina-tribes.jar,jasper.jar,jasper-el.jar,ecj-*.jar,tomcat-api.jar,tomcat-util.jar,tomcat-util-scan.jar,tomcat-coyote.jar,tomcat-dbcp.jar,tomcat-jni.jar,tomcat-websocket.jar,tomcat-i18n-en.jar,tomcat-i18n-es.jar,tomcat-i18n-fr.jar,tomcat-i18n-ja.jar,tomcat-juli-adapters.jar,catalina-jmx-remote.jar,catalina-ws.jar,tomcat-jdbc.jar,tools.jar,commons-beanutils*.jar,commons-codec*.jar,commons-collections*.jar,commons-dbcp*.jar,commons-digester*.jar,commons-fileupload*.jar,commons-httpclient*.jar,commons-io*.jar,commons-lang*.jar,commons-logging*.jar,commons-math*.jar,commons-pool*.jar,jstl.jar,taglibs-standard-spec-*.jar,geronimo-spec-jaxrpc*.jar,wsdl4j*.jar,ant.jar,ant-junit*.jar,aspectj*.jar,jmx.jar,h2*.jar,hibernate*.jar,httpclient*.jar,jmx-tools.jar,jta*.jar,log4j*.jar,mail*.jar,slf4j*.jar,xercesImpl.jar,xmlParserAPIs.jar,xml-apis.jar,junit.jar,junit-*.jar,hamcrest-*.jar,easymock-*.jar,cglib-*.jar,objenesis-*.jar,ant-launcher.jar,cobertura-*.jar,asm-*.jar,dom4j-*.jar,icu4j-*.jar,jaxen-*.jar,jdom-*.jar,jetty-*.jar,oro-*.jar,servlet-api-*.jar,tagsoup-*.jar,xmlParserAPIs-*.jar,xom-*.jar, catalina.home=/opt/tomcat, java.class.path=/opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar, user.name=root, java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory, package.definition=sun.,java.,org.apache.catalina.,org.apache.coyote.,org.apache.jasper.,org.apache.naming.,org.apache.tomcat., java.vm.specification.version=1.8, sun.java.command=org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start, java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/jre8, sun.arch.data.model=64, user.language=en, java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, awt.toolkit=sun.awt.X11.XToolkit, java.vm.info=mixed mode, java.version=1.8.0_161, java.ext.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/jre8/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext, sun.boot.class.path=/usr/lib/jvm/jre8/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jre8/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jre8/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jre8/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jre8/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jre8/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jre8/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jre8/classes, server.loader=, java.vendor=Oracle Corporation, catalina.base=/opt/tomcat, jdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048, file.separator=/, java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/, common.loader="${catalina.base}/lib","${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar","${catalina.home}/lib","${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar", sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle, sun.cpu.endian=little, package.access=sun.,org.apache.catalina.,org.apache.coyote.,org.apache.jasper.,org.apache.tomcat., sun.cpu.isalist=}}, SystemEnvironmentPropertySource@945732227 {name='systemEnvironment', properties={PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/tomcat/bin, TOMCAT_VERSION=8.5.24, HOSTNAME=1dac3826ef98, JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre8, CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat, JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS= --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED, PWD=/opt/tomcat, HOME=/root, SHLVL=0}}]
13:28:10.345 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Replacing PropertySource 'servletContextInitParams' with 'servletContextInitParams'
```

(This happens before the Spring application start)

I have tried a docker image from ubuntu with oracle java and tomcat manually installed and the official tomcat image.

[Complete Log](https://gist.github.com/mwanders98/1f2af55c9051465062d44138f01c9b54)

Comment: It seems to me error related to spring-boot, not able to find the dependency, can you please share your dockerfile? Can you check on MAC host, docker container is having internet connectivity to download dependency?

Comment: Hello, in the moment I am using the tomcat:9.0.8-jre8-alpine image and deployed the war file by hand. The container has working internet.

Answer (score 0):

From the logs:

`Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same packag`e`

it seems that you have two JARs of the [apache-commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/) component in the server classpath, and those JAR files have signatures signed with different certificates.

Check your classpath and remove one of the JARs or remove the signatures from the manifest of conflicting JARs.

Seeing that you use Apache Axis which has a runtime dependency on `apache-commons` I would try to specifically exclude the jar from the built.